# Find Mode and 2nd mode for given list

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def mode(x):
    """returns a list, might be more than one mode"""
    counts = Counter(x)
    max_count = max(counts.values())
    return [x_i for x_i, count in counts.items() if count == max_count]


num_grp = [57,61,65,63,63,64,64,65,63,67,66,71,75,67,67,70,74,81,85]
num_friends = ['Silver','Platinum','Gold','Gold','Silver','Silver',
    'Bronze','Silver','Platinum','Platinum','Silver','Gold','Platinum',
    'Silver','Platinum','Silver','Platinum','Platinum','Gold','Silver']
d={
    'Policy':['Silver','Platinum','Gold','Gold','Silver','Silver','Bronze',
    'Silver','Platinum','Platinum','Silver','Gold','Platinum','Silver',
    'Platinum','Silver','Platinum','Platinum','Gold','Silver'],
    'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]}

print("Mode for group list:",mode(num_grp))
print("Mode for friend list:",mode(num_friends))

f = pd.DataFrame(d)

f['Policy'].mode()
```

With this code also, when list of "integers" (`num_grp`) is taken it gives two output. But when list of "strings" (`num_friends`) is taken it gives one output as shown above

The same code when used with list of strings gives only single "mode" value is obtained,

The above code should give output :['Silver', 'Platinum'] 
Instead it gives a single output ['Silver']

Comment: sorry what's the question here?

Comment: The question is a. Based on this data calculate the following summary statistics for the POLICY
feature:
i. Mode and 2nd mode for given data . The code I posted are two different codes

Comment: edit it back to how it was, it’s unreadable again

Comment: The posted code is a mess. Please separate your code from output, provide a clear [mcve] that is independent from expected output, separated by clear statements of which is which. And please clearly state your question, and rephrase your title to be more clear. As is, it's dificult ot make sense of the post.

Comment: I apologize for inconvenience caused, new to stackoverflow. I am trying to improve my post.

Comment: No worries! It's just a little learning curve. For one thing, it's important that your code be readable and indented just as if you were looking at it in a code editor or IDE. Make sure it includes everything it might need to actually run, and clearly illustrates the problem. :)

Comment: For example, what is `Counter(x)`? that doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: And perhaps define both `num_grp` and `num_friends` at the top of one example block, with `mode(num_friends)` followed by `mode(num_friends)` in the same example. And the Output listed as a separate block. It's easier to read and takes up less space.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Chris...I am using Jupyter Notebook. I imported pandas , and the code worked fine. Still I will look into it

Comment: You're welcome! I made an edit to try to make it a bit more clear. See what you think, and if it fairly represents what you have.

Comment: Redo the questions at the end to match the code example above.

Comment: And it looks like I left out the outputs. You should add those again as their own block or blocks.